# Want to download images from website in stead of json file

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

We need the images from the website <https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images >.But the below script download json file.But we want to download images directly .I am beginner .Thanks in advance

```
    from threading import Timer
    import time
    import requests

    startlog = time.time()
    image_url = "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images"


    tm = 0
    while True:
        tm += 1
        r = requests.get(image_url)  # create HTTP response object
        with open(str(tm)+"trafficFile.json", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)

   print(tm)
   time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Did you check how the output is returning from that api? Check the other variables of r.

Answer (score 0):

This small piece of code written above will download the following image from the web. Now check your local directory(the folder where this script resides), and you will find this image.

Comment: the written above code download only json file.but i want to download the images directly. .